# Error: PickerView " cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return type 'String?' "

Tags: swift, xcode, datepicker, uipickerview

Using a PickerView in Xcode Swift getting the error in this code:

```
func pickerView(pikcerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerDate [row] // Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return type 'String?'

        }
```

Full code of the PickerView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputpickerdate: UIPickerView!

   // var pickerList = ["test","test2","test3"]

    var pickerDate: [[String]] = [[String]] ()
        //[pickerModel] ()

    var selected: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.inputpickerdate.delegate = self
    self.inputpickerdate.dataSource = self

        pickerDate = [["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"], ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"], ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]]


 func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 3
    }


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return pickerDate.count
        }
func pickerView(pikcerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerDate [row]

        }
```

I am trying to create a PickerView with the Date of the Week, the Day, and the Month, for example, Monday 2 March

However, I have done it this way and getting the

> error: cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return
>   type 'String?'

in my `func titleForRow` and not sure why I am getting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using wrong `titleForRow` delegate method. it should be:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
```

and next thing is you need to replace

```
return pickerDate [row]
```

with

```
return pickerDate[component][row]
```

and your method will be:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDate[component][row]
}
```

And your picker will look like:

[image]

Comment: Happy to help and don't forget to mark answer as correct if that helps you.

Comment: No you didn't.. :)

Comment: Sadly now getting the error - Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range - any ideas?

Comment: It's because you are trying to access the index which is not there in your Array.

Answer (score 1):

You've a list of list.

`[]` -> a list.

`[[]]` -> list of list.

You is returning a list `[]` instead a `String?`.
In your case, you must use something like this:

```
func pickerView(pikcerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerDate[component][row] // if component starts with 0.
}
```

Of course, you must make a logic to get your correct field.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the string of Array = `return pickerDate [row]` where it should be a single string.